# json expects a property "@class". How to define in c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm interacting with an API where the expected json includes a property called "@class".

For clarification (and as has been asked on here a number of times), if the property was simply called "class" then you can add the symbol "@" in front to escape the fact that we're using a reserved word, such as :

```
public string @class { get; set; }
```

In this case however the property name includes the "@" symbol. There is no way I can change the definition of the class as it's not mine to change.

As you may expect json2csharp doesn't like it, and running the example json through it returns:

```
public string __invalid_name__@class { get; set; }
```

Which seems entirely reasonable!

Is there any way round this other than using string.replace on the json immediately before sending it (which to me feels dirty!)?

Comment: what json library are you using?

Comment: json.net - I was daft to omit that! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use Json.NET, you can easily specify it via attribute:

```
public class Test
{
    [JsonProperty("@class")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does this still work with the latest json.net version? I am trying to achieve exactly this and pulling my hair out because my c# property stays NULL upon deserialization. Searching SO up and down I keep finding this solution, alas it wont work...

Comment: @quaylar what you ask is different question. So you should create new question and provide minimal example to reproduce it.